# How to format JSON Output into a Grid for Format-Table in PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell, invoke-restmethod

The following code is display the data I want, but it's not aligned nicely.
How can I use a data-grid or format-table to align the data?

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod @params
foreach ( $row in $response )
{
    Write-host "id=$($row.uuid) uuid=$($row.uuid) Subject=$($row.subject) " 
}
```

Example output now:

```
id=new-template_1 uuid=new-template_1 Subject=Welcome! 
id=new-template_3 uuid=new-template_3 Subject=Welcome!
```

Desired:

```
    id              uuid             subject 
new_template_1    new_template_1    Welcome! 
new_template_3    new_template_3    Welcome!
```

Comment: Change your `write-host` to, `[pscustomobject]@{ 'id'=$row.uuid ...}`

Comment: `Invoke-RestMethod @params |Select-Object @{Name='id';Expression='uuid'},uuid,Subject`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a "trimmed" set of properties from the objects output by `Invoke-RestMethod`, use `Select-Object`:

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod @params
$trimmedResponse = $response |Select-Object @{Name='id';Expression='uuid'},uuid,subject

# This will now default to table view formatting
$trimmedResponse

# But you can also explicitly pipe to `Format-Table` 
$trimmedResponse |Format-Table

# ... allowing you greater control over the formatting behavior
$trimmedResponse |Sort-Object Subject |Format-Table -GroupBy Subject
```

The first argument passed to `Select-Object` (`@{Name='id';Expression='uuid'}`) is known as a [*calculated property*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties) - in this case it defines a new property named `id`, with the value of the `uuid` property of the input object.